# How to set different breaks and labels on the scales when facetting data in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

Consider the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)    
data = data.frame(x = c(1, 2,
                        3, 4,
                        5, 6),
                  label = c("foo", "bar",
                            "bar", "baz",
                            "baz", "boo"),
                  type = c(1, 1,
                           2, 2,
                           3, 3))
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = c(1))) +
    labs(x = "", y = "") +
    theme_bw() +
    facet_wrap(~ type, ncol = 1, scales = "free_x") +
    scale_x_discrete(aes(breaks = x, labels=label), limits = 1:6) +
    geom_point()
```

It generates the image:

[image: image plot]

The problem is that my `scale_x_discrete()` is ignored. I would like each facet's x scale to show the labels in `data$label`, but only where there is data. In other words, I would like something like this, but on a single chart:

[image: facet]

[image: facet]

[image: facet]

How can I do it?

Comment: I think there's a typo in your code, to produce those charts you need: `ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = c(1)))` instead of `ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = c(0)))`

Comment: You're right. I've fixed the code, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to construct the plots separately, then combine them using `grid.arrange`:

```
library(ggplot2)    
data = data.frame(x = c(1, 2,
                        3, 4,
                        5, 6),
                  label = c("foo", "bar",
                            "bar", "baz",
                            "baz", "boo"),
                  type = c(1, 1,
                           2, 2,
                           3, 3))

library(gridExtra)  # Using V 2.0.0

p = list()

for(i in 1:3) {

df = subset(data, type == i)

p[[i]] = ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = c(1)) ) +
    labs(x = "", y = "") +
    theme_bw() +
    expand_limits(x = c(1, 6)) + 
    facet_wrap(~ type, ncol = 1) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = df$x, labels = df$label) +
    geom_point()
   }

grid.arrange(grobs = p, ncol = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Sandy, are you able to keep the limits on all x scales the same? I tried modifying your code but couldn't do it.

Comment: I've changed the plot and the code.   Do I understand this time?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing as well. It seems there's no way to do what we're trying to with a single plot. I'll accept your answer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Changing the argument to `scales = "free"`. I modified the example adding 'y = type` instead of the constant c(1) to get different scales.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = type)) +
  labs(x = "", y = "") +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(~ type, ncol = 1, scales = "free") +
  scale_x_discrete(aes(breaks = x), labels = data$label, limits = 1:6) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Using `scales = "free_y"`

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = type)) +
  labs(x = "", y = "") +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(~ type, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y") +
  scale_x_discrete(aes(breaks = x), labels = data$label, limits = 1:6) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = label, y = type)) +
  labs(x = "", y = "") +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(~ type, ncol = 1, scales = "free") +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: @nongkrong Not sure if this is closer to the question that the OP had in mind.

Comment: there is a `PANEL` variable you might be able to use

Comment: @mpalanco thanks for your answer, but this doesn't work for me. What I'm looking for is your first chart, but with the axis breaks different for each facet. The first one should have just foo and bar, the second bar and baz, the third baz and boo. The `y` should be constant as well.

What I'm trying is to show is change in time. Each `type` means a time: t1, t2 and t3, and the positions of the data changes over time. You can see that `bar` changed from 2 at t1 to 3 at t2, and `baz` changed from 3 at t2 to 4 at t3. That's why the breaks must be different on each facet.

Comment: @VítorBaptista In the last one you can see the change in time by looking at the y-axis. For instance, bar changed from 1 in t1 to 2 in t2.

Comment: @mpalanco I see... still, I think that keeping time on the x axis is much less confusing. Not sure if it's possible with a single chart in ggplot, though